# Save and load array in and from a file

Tags: c#, file, multidimensional-array, streamreader, streamwriter

I need to save multidimensional array into file. Then be able to change things in that so it will also appear in that file and load from said file into array.

Let's say I have some array:

```csh
private string[,] array = new string[5, 5];
```

Then I need to do a function, that will fill the array with space if file does not exist and if it does, load it. Something like this:

```csh
        private void Load()
        {
            if (File.Exists("save.txt"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        array[i,j] = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I checked if the file exists, if not I will fill the array with spaces but then I need in some way write the array in the file in this format:

```
" ", " ", " "," ", " ",
" ", " ", " "," ", " ",
" ", " ", " "," ", " ",
" ", " ", " "," ", " ",
" ", " ", " "," ", " ",
 or in some format, that will work.
```

Then I basically planned to split the string with ',' and save it to that array. And if file exists, read it and save the values to said array.

So basically I need to check if the file exist, if the answer is yes, load it to the multidimensional array, If the answer is no, fill the array with empty strings and load that in the file.

If somebody is willing to help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Considering you tagged `StreamReader` and and `StreamWriter` in your question, how come haven't you implemented them into your script to achieve what you need?

Comment: You basically summed up what you need to do, what more do you need to know? there's plenty of documentation on streamreaders, so i'm not sure what the question is...

Comment: Why not use an established format like CSV, JSON, XML for this purpose? There are well established ways and write and read these formats.